# Tell bazel to copy .so file into py_library output folder?

Tags: python, bazel

I have a py_library that depends on an *.so file. I have a cc_library rule that creates the .so file. I added the name of the cc_library to the data field of the py_library, but bazel doesn't place a copy of the *.so into the output folder.

```
cc_binary(
    name = "_python_api.so",
    linkshared = True,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "...",
    ],
)

py_library(
    name = "python_api",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    imports = [
        "python_api",
    ],
    srcs = [
        "python_api/python_api.py"
    ],
    data = [
        ":_python_api.so",
    ],
)

py_binary(
    name = "python_api_example",
    srcs = [
        "python_api_example.py",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":python_api",
    ],
)
```

Everything compiles correctly. But when I run the example app, it says it cannot find _python_api.so. I can see _python_api.so in the output folder, just not in the same folder as python_api.py. If I create a symlink in the same folder as python_api.py to the _python_api.so file then everything works.

Is there a way I can tell bazel that this so file needs to be in the same folder as python_api.py?

Comment: What struck me is that you define your library as `cc_binary`. When building libraries as `cc_library`, bazel's magic wrapping python execution seem to result in being able to find (`import`) shared libraries from `data` attribute. Or at least I've tried a small example akin to yours with mentioned difference and it seems to work on my machine as expected. :)